# name 'win32' is not defined

Tags: python, undefined, pywin32, win32com

I am working on python and I would like to export data from sql server to excel, I’ve installed and upgraded the pywin32 from command prompt but I took the same error again and again.
Is there any different solution?
[Here is my code and my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uVO.png)

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and prepare a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the import statement use:

import win32com.client as win32

'as win32' define the name to use the package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).